# How to center a form that is on the same line as an image?

Tags: html, css, image, forms, header

I know this is probably very simple, but I seem to be struggling! But basically in my `<header>` I want to have my logo on the left and then a form which acts as a search engine in the middle (so all on the same line). heres my current code for it:

```
<header>
    <div class="image"> <img class="logo" src="Logo.jpg"> </div>
    <div class="form">
        <form id="WhatsHappening" action = "index.php" method="post">
            <input type="text" class="input" name="location" id="location">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" hidden="true">
        </form>  
    </div>
</header>
```

and the css:

```css
.image{
    float:left;
}

.form{
    float:left;
}

img{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}

#WhatsHappening input[type="text"] {
    width: 200px;
}

#WhatsHappening {   
    text-align:center;
}
```

Any help would be really appreciated! thank you in advance!

Comment: what's the problem so far? It would be useful if you explain what results are you getting and why then don't work as expected. As far as I can see, both the image and the form are on the same line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change your `.form{float:left;}` to `text-align: center;`

```
.form
{
    text-align: center;
}
```

[**Demo Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/NmP69/1/)

Comment: Wow such quick responses! thank you everyone! this one seemed to do the trick though:)

Answer (score 0):

You need a parent div to hold the two divs:

Here is a 3 div layout, e.g:

```
<div style="width: 800px;">
 <div style="float: left; width: 300px;">Left Stuff</div>
 <div style="float: left; width: 200px;">Middle Stuff</div>
 <div style="float: left; width: 300px;">Right Stuff</div>
 <br style="clear: left;" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code..  it's simple i think :)

```
<header>
    <div class="image" align="left"> <img class="logo" src="Logo.jpg"> </div>
    <div class="form" align="center" >
        <form id="WhatsHappening" action = "index.php" method="post">
            <input type="text" class="input" name="location" id="location">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" hidden="true">
        </form>  
    </div>
</header>
```